# Is there a way to have custom attributes not be ignored in docbook when converting from asciidoc?

Tags: docbook, asciidoctor

For a project we'd like documentations written in asciidoc to be converted to  pdf.
We do so by creating a docbook .xml file using asciidoctor, then convert the docbook file with Apache FOP to pdf.

For header, footer and title page we need some metadata, which we set in attributes such as `:orgname:` `:revdate:` etc..

Problem is, not all attributes are passed over to docbook, some get lost when creating a docbook file via asciidoctor.

e.g. When setting `:foo: bar` it won't appear anywhere within the xml document.

Is there a way to overcome this limitation?

The perfect solution for us would be to have attributes such as confidentiality to appear within the article info tag in the xml file.

Comment: The template which is used for the conversion needs to know about specific tags to add to the info tag.  In general, custom attributes in AsciiDoc are intended for substitution, not meta data.  So if you define the attribute :foo: bar, then wherever you put {foo} in the document, it will be replaced with the value "bar", unless the template used for the conversion specifically knows how to treat it differently.  To do what you want to do, you will need to edit the template yourself to accommodate the attributes in the way that you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
With template you mean the template asciidoctor uses to convert adoc to docbook, right?

Can you give me a hint as in where to find the default template asciidoctor uses by default to convert to docbook.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how the templates work.  But, looking at the installation I have, in AsciiDoctor language they refer to "converters" instead of template.  They are located in the installation directory in the "gems" sub-directory: {adoc_installation_dir}/gems/asciidoctor-1.5.6.1/lib/asciidoctor/converter.  If you open up, say, docbook5.rb, you'll see that it looks for specific attributes right at the top: "if node.attr? 'sectnums' ..." etc.